# How I can change owner of files written by php

Tags: apache, terminal, file-permissions

How can I change the owner of the files written by php from terminal (command line)? The files are created by upload form in apposite folder.

Many thaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command "chown":

```
chown owner filenames
```

To solve this problem in the future uploads, you can use the chown command:

```
chown($path, $user_name);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

There is also a chmod command, if you prefer to change permissions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'd like that every new files writen by PHP in a particular folder is set with a particular owner. I hope I was clearly

Comment: The files will be created with the PHP user as a owner. If you want to change that, you will have to use chown from PHP itself (after the file upload). The method is the same, but from the PHP file.

Comment: In my web space, I can write new files only if i set the permission to 777; I prefer avoid.. and set the folder to 775; I ask a solution for this reason

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change the owner within the PHP program itself (of course if you have the permission to do that) with the `exec` command of PHP.

For example:

```
exec('whoami');
```

See the documentation of this php instruction here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

This could work, but only if the servers configuration allows so.

If this doesn't work, you can try also this, but again you need some priviledges to do it:

```
// File name and username to use
$file_name= "foo.php";
$path = "/home/sites/php.net/public_html/sandbox/" . $file_name ;
$user_name = "root";

// Set the user
chown($path, $user_name);
```

See the documentation of this php instruction here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

There are some instructions in php to modify file attributes like, chmod, chown, among others.

Comment: thanks jltorresm; if my server don't allows this function? There is an alternative solution?