# fopen creates files owned by root in php

Tags: php, file-permissions

I'm writing the code for converting disqus comments to HashOver system, and I have code like this:

```
// $threads is list of threads from disqus api that I cached on disk
foreach ($threads as $thread) {
    $dir_name = getSafeThreadName(preg_replace("%^https?://[^/]+%", "", $thread['link']));
    $dir = 'threads/' . $dir_name;
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir);
        chmod($dir, 0774);
    }
    // ...
    // $thread_posts are $post that belong to $thread
    foreach($thread_posts as $post) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<comment/>');
        // ...
        // $name_arr is array of numbers for HashOver comments
        $fname = $dir . '/' . implode('-', $name_arr) . ".xml";
        $f = fopen($fname, 'w');
        fwrite($f, $xml->asXML());
        fclose($f);
        chmod($fname, 0664);
    }
}
```

it created directory for each of my posts in threads that that is read/write with owner `apache:apache` and inside there are files like `1.xml` with owner `root:root`

why `root:root`? How can I make it `apache:apache`?

**EDIT:**

This is no a duplicate, I don't want to change permission to `apache:apache` from `root:root`, which can be done using `chown`, but I want to make it so it don't change it to `root:root` in first place, I also want to know why it changed to `root:root`. This looks like a bug in php or apache for me or some wrong configuration in apache on my side. I don't think is the code since it just open, write and close file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can change owner of files written by php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663516/how-i-can-change-owner-of-files-written-by-php)

Comment: Are you running this in the browser or using CLI

Comment: @RiggsFolly from browser.

Comment: @DaFois this is not duplicate because it's not changing permission but making it so it don't change to `root:root` but keep `apache:apache` like for other files, and when looking some other question it seems that for chown you will need to modify sudoerrs which is not an option for me.

Comment: Looks like your server is misconfigured and the Apache process is actually running as root.

Comment: @jrswgtr `echo exec('whoami')` displays `apache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why and I would like to know, but this solve the issue:

I've use this:

```
chmod($dir, 0775);
```

instead of:

```
chmod($dir, 0774);
```

directory was not executable for others and it make files in that directory owned by root when created. Very weird.